# How to alter column of a table with indexes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, alter-table

I would like to change the column size of the a column in a table with some indexes from varchar(200) to varchar(8000). How should I proceed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since is `VARCHAR` and you're increasing the size, then simply [`ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql) should be enough.

> The data type of columns included in an index cannot be changed **unless** the column is a varchar, nvarchar, or varbinary data type, and the new size is equal to or larger than the old size.

Otherwise you would drop the index(es), alter the column, then add back the index(es).

Be aware though that SQL Server [*maximum index key size*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server) is 900 (or 1700 for newer editions), so even though the ALTER will succeed, a future `INSERT` of 
 data over the 900 length limit will fail with error:

```
Msg 1946, Level 16, State 3, Line 13
Operation failed. The index entry of length ... bytes for the index '...' exceeds the maximum length of 900 bytes.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this for MSSQL:

```
drop index person.idx_pers_fullname
ALTER table person alter COLUMN  pers_firstname nvarchar(8000)
create index idx_pers_fullname on person(pers_firstname)
```

Comment: nvarchar limit is 4000. Beyond that you need to use nvarchar(max)

Answer (score -4):

Example in `Oracle`:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP (NAME VARCHAR(200));

ALTER TABLE  EMP MODIFY  NAME VARCHAR(800);
```